# Naturally compare two alphanumeric strings to see if one is less than the other

Tags: php, string, comparison, alphanumeric, natural-sort

I have 2 strings:

```
$string_1 = 'c5';
$string_2 = 'c6';
```

And I want to check if `$string_2` comes *after* or *before* `$string_1` if both were ordered in an alphabetic order.

So in the examples above, `$string_2` comes *after* `$string_1`. But if value of `$string_2` was `c2`, then it would become before `$string_1`...

What's a solid approach to do this check with a boolean result?

### What I've tried so far

I can add strings into an array, order array by alphabetic order, and then check which whether if `$string_2` as `$key` value `0` or `1`.

### EDIT

Note that `c2` should come **before** `c11`.

Comment: Write piece of code where you convert char into number (c - 3 or 12?) and compare ints

Comment: @Eakethet It's not always integers, which is why I am going with alphabetic order...

Comment: uhm, can you write down some usecase with some edgecase eg.? Like can $string_2 be like "ab12"?

Comment: @Eakethet Yes it can be. It can for examples be string 1: `hello world`  and string 2: 'lorem ipsum'

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is now, resp. how a simple `<` comparison would not achieve what you need already …?

Comment: @misorude are you telling me this works `'abc' < 'dfg'`

Comment: This is called lexical order and that should make it trivial to find out how to do it. BTW: Consider `c2` and `c11`, which should come first?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson added an answer, but I'm still not sure if i understand you correctly

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Excellent point. `c2` comes before `c11`!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, what is your logic? `c2` comes before `c11` because of their length or `2` < `11` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the array, sort it, using [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php), and get the name of the variable with a less value

```
$string_1 = 'c5';
$string_2 = 'c6';
$res = compact('string_1', 'string_2'); // ['string_1' => 'c5', 'string_2' => 'c6']
natsort($res);
echo key($res); // name of variable with less value
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1053414)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 7+, you can use the [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) `<=>` to compare the two fields.

```
$string_1 = 'c5';
$string_2 = 'c6';

echo ($string_1 <=> $string_2).PHP_EOL;
echo ($string_2 <=> $string_1).PHP_EOL;
echo ($string_1 <=> $string_1).PHP_EOL;
```

will output

```
-1    // 1st  is before 2nd
1     // 2nd is before 1st
0     // 1st is same as 2nd
```

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Please don't edit the question after people have answered unless really necessary, this can sometimes make all the answers invalid!

Comment: This is very necessary to clarify the ordering being lexical order.

Answer (score 1):

use strpos()

```
$string_1 = "c2";
$string_2 = "c5";
$bigString = $string_1.$string_2; // Hypothetical string with string_1 and string_2 in alphabethical order in it
if(strpos($bigString, $string_1) > strpos($bigString, $string_2)) {
  echo 'true';
}
else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie Do you have an alternative approach?

Comment: @Alive to Die What do you mean... Not working? It does.

Comment: @DieterKräutl You have misunderstood the question. Its not about the order in which the variables are concatted.

Comment: I do understand. I just concated them so its clear what bigString could be. I am aware that He does not know exactly what order they are in. @Xatenev

Comment: @DieterKräutl But in the eval of Alive to Die you can then see that the output should be string 2 comes first because `c2` is before `c5`. But the output is string 1 comes first which is wrong. (Judged from the example of OP.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is answer for your question, but if I understand correctly, I would write function like this:

```
<?php

$a = 'test';
$b = 'vest';

function comp($one, $two) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < strlen($one) && $i < strlen($two)) {
        if (ord($one[$i]) > ord($two[$i])) {
            return true;
        } elseif (ord($one[$i]) < ord($two[$i])) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

var_dump(comp($a, $b));
var_dump(comp($b, $a));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `int` [strcasecmp](http://www.php.net/strcasecmp) `( string $str1 , string $str2 )`.

https://eval.in/1053409

```
<?php
$string_1 = 'd';
$string_2 = 'c';

// Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.
$return = strcasecmp($string_1, $string_2);

if($return < 0) {
echo "$string_1 is before $string_2";
} else if($return > 0) {
echo "$string_1 is after $string_2";
} else {
echo "$string_1 and $string_2 are equal";
}
```

> d is after c

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated native function for this task -- it provides a 3-way comparison (rightly so).  `strnatcmp()` will "naturally" compare two strings and return -1 if the first value is less than the second, 0 if they are the identical, and 1 if the first value is larger than the second.

However you wish to implement the check against the returned integer is up to you.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v6vOL))

```
$string_1 = 'c5';
$string_2 = 'c11';
$string_3 = 'c329';
$string_4 = 'c78';

echo "Min: " . match (strnatcmp($string_1, $string_2)) {
        -1 => $string_1,
        0 => 'same',
        1 => $string_2
};

echo "\n---\nMin: " . match (strnatcmp($string_3, $string_4)) {
        -1 => $string_3,
        0 => 'same',
        1 => $string_4
};
```

Output:

```
Min: c5
---
Min: c78
```